# Display different aspx file in a popup in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently developing an ASP.net application. I am generating a table (standard HTML table not GridView) and populating it with data from a MySQL Database. One column of the table has hyperlinks which should link to a dynamic aspx web page that will display certain information based on the database.

When the user clicks on the hyperlink I want to display a pop up that hovers over the top of the original content, not opening a new browser window just displaying like a popup window which will darken the contents of the background content.

I have tried to google search this but did not find anything.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: [LightBox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Answer (score 0):

The AjaxControlToolkit has a control for this. See http://www.asp.net/ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dialog control from the jquery UI library if you want to use jquery:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/